Using Parted, Gdisk, fdisk or other tools to re-format an Android device
I have a Lenovo Yoga tablet 2 Android version which uses an Intel chip.
I have managed to install TWRP on the device.
I need to use a tool in the TWRP command line environment to resize the partitions on Android and also see if I could install Ubuntu.
I found this guide:
How to run "parted" command in terminal emulator on my android smartphone
However the tools are all for ARM CPUs and mine is an Intel one.
I also have the deb files for the tools on my x86-64 Ubuntu PC. But the terminal in TWRP cannot install deb files as there is no dpkg I think.
How do I get such tools running?

Even if the CPU is PC alike, regular Ubuntu will not work because Android devices do not have a BIOS/UEFI which you could use to boot Ubuntu.

Yes it does. You just need a terminal to get into the UEFI. It lets you boot from a file too.

Here is the code:

adb shell
su
mount -t efivarfs efivarfs /sys/firmware/efi/efivars
printf "\x07\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00" > /sys/firmware/efi/efivars/OsIndications-8be4df61-93ca-11d2-aa0d-00e098032b8c
reboot

Please make it a proper answer giving all details. It will help others and you may earn some reputation if the answer is well written with all details
